# I am trying to use KEA keyword extraction algorithm

Tags: java, keyword-search, keyword-extraction

I downloaded the latest jar file (https://code.google.com/p/kea-algorithm/) and added it to my classpath in eclipse. But I am getting the following error "The type weka.core.OptionHandler cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files"  I am getting this error when setting the PorterStemmer.

If you know any other keyword extraction tool that can be used with java I would appreciate it!

```
'''import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

import kea.main.KEAKeyphraseExtractor;
import kea.main.KEAModelBuilder;
import kea.stemmers.*;
import kea.stopwords.*;

public class KeywordExtractor {
    private KEAModelBuilder km;
    private KEAKeyphraseExtractor ke;

    private void setOptionsTraining() throws FileNotFoundException {

        km = new KEAModelBuilder();

        // A. required arguments (no defaults):

        // 1. Name of the directory -- give the path to your directory with documents
        // and keyphrases
        // documents should be in txt format with an extention "txt"
        // keyphrases with the same name as documents, but extension "key"
        // one keyphrase per line!
        km.setDirName("testdocs/en/train");

        // 2. Name of the model -- give the path to where the model is to be stored and
        // its name
        km.setModelName("testdocs/en/model");

        // 3. Name of the vocabulary -- name of the file (without extension) that is
        // stored in VOCABULARIES
        // or "none" if no Vocabulary is used (free keyphrase extraction).
        km.setVocabulary("none");

        // 4. Format of the vocabulary in 3. Leave empty if vocabulary = "none", use
        // "skos" or "txt" otherwise.
        km.setVocabularyFormat("none");

        //B. optional arguments if you want to change the defaults
        // 5. Encoding of the document
        km.setEncoding("UTF-8");

        // 6. Language of the document -- use "es" for Spanish, "fr" for French
        // or other languages as specified in your "skos" vocabulary
        km.setDocumentLanguage("en"); // es for Spanish, fr for French

        // 7. Stemmer -- adjust if you use a different language than English or if you
        // want to alterate results
        // (We have obtained better results for Spanish and French with NoStemmer)
        km.getStemmer(new PorterStemmer());

        // 8. Stopwords -- adjust if you use a different language than English!
        km.setStopwords(new StopwordsEnglish());

        // 9. Maximum length of a keyphrase
        km.setMaxPhraseLength(5);

        // 10. Minimum length of a keyphrase
        km.setMinPhraseLength(1);

        // 11. Minumum occurrence of a phrase in the document -- use 2 for long
        // documents!
        km.setMinNumOccur(2);

        // Optional: turn off the keyphrase frequency feature
        // km.setUseKFrequency(false);

    }

    private void setOptionsTesting(String m_testdir) throws FileNotFoundException {

        ke = new KEAKeyphraseExtractor();

        // A. required arguments (no defaults):

        // 1. Name of the directory -- give the path to your directory with documents
        // documents should be in txt format with an extention "txt".
        // Note: keyphrases with the same name as documents, but extension "key"
        // one keyphrase per line!

        ke.setDirName(m_testdir);

        // 2. Name of the model -- give the path to the model
        // needs to be on classpath (i.e. include '.' in classpath for this to work)
        ke.setModelName("/testdocs/en/model");

        // 3. Name of the vocabulary -- name of the file (without extension) that is
        // stored in VOCABULARIES
        // or "none" if no Vocabulary is used (free keyphrase extraction).
        ke.setVocabulary("none");

       // 4. Format of the vocabulary in 3. Leave empty if vocabulary = "none", use "skos" or "txt" otherwise.
        ke.setVocabularyFormat("none");

        // B. optional arguments if you want to change the defaults
        // 5. Encoding of the document
        ke.setEncoding("UTF-8");

        // 6. Language of the document -- use "es" for Spanish, "fr" for French
        // or other languages as specified in your "skos" vocabulary
        ke.setDocumentLanguage("en"); // es for Spanish, fr for French

        // 7. Stemmer -- adjust if you use a different language than English or want to
        // alterate results
        // (We have obtained better results for Spanish and French with NoStemmer)
        ke.setStemmer(new PorterStemmer());

        // 8. Stopwords
        ke.setStopwords(new StopwordsEnglish());

        // 9. Number of Keyphrases to extract
        ke.setNumPhrases(10);

        // 10. Set to true, if you want to compute global dictionaries from the test
        // collection
        ke.setBuildGlobal(false);

        ke.setAdditionalInfo(true);

    }

    private void createModel() {
        try {
            km.buildModel(km.collectStems());
            km.saveModel();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    private void extractKeyphrases() {
        try {
            ke.loadModel();
            ke.extractKeyphrases(ke.collectStems());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}
'''
```

Comment: Read the documentation of the library you're using, and make sure you add all its required dependencies.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I added the weka jar file however now I have this error 
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: weka.core.Attribute.<init>(Ljava/lang/String;Lweka/core/FastVector;)V   Should I create a new question?

Comment: Then you probably added the wrong version of Weka.